# what is probability? You roll two ordinary dice, and their total is 2 or their total is 12.

Tags: probability

so I tried this some like this:

1. there are total 11 possibilities here (there are two dices to total can't be 1 and possibilities are 2 to 12)
2. and then I came to the answer of 2/11 (since there are two possibilities in 11)

---

but in the book the answer is 1/18.

Comment: There are $11$ possibilities, but the different possibilities do not have equal probability. Alternatively, take the view of the answer below that all possibilities have equal probability, but there aren't $11$ of them.

Comment: There are $36$ possibilities. Some of them are identical, nevertheless, there are $36$ of them.

Comment: Thans Arthur. I got it now (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this table for easier visualization. The column and row represent the first and second die roll, and the cell in the intersection is the sum of the two rolls. Since some sums appear more than once, they are more likely to happen than the ones appearing more rarely. $7$ is the most likely outcome, as no matter what the first roll is, the second roll always has a $1/6$ chance of bringing the total to seven.

You can count the occurrences of the desired numbers from the table and divide by 36 (the number possible combinations) to figure out the probability of rolling those numbers.

$$\begin{array}{c|c c c c c } 
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Yeah. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't $11$ total possibilities. The possibilities are:

- $1+1$
- $1+2$
- $1+3$
- $1+4$
- $1+5$
- $1+6$
- $2+1$
- $2+2$
- $2+3$
- $2+4$

and so on.

For example, there are a total of $6$ equally probable possiblities that all sum to $7$, i.e. $1+6, 2+5, 3+4, 4+3, 5+2, 6+1$.